# Cannot find a code example for http client / server with EXI compression as a payload

Tags: exi

After couple of days of research I cannot find a good example for client that sends http request with data that was compressed using EXI.
I tried to do it by myself in nodejs but without success.
I took the following sample:
https://github.com/EXIficient/exificient.js

```
   `var EXIEncoder = require('exificient.js');
    var exiEncoder = new EXIEncoder();  
    exiEncoder.encodeXmlText(textXML);
    var uint8ArrayLength = exiEncoder.getUint8ArrayLength();
    var uint8Array = exiEncoder.getUint8Array();`
```

but I did not succeed to execute this code, "EXIEncoder is not a constructor".
Somebody could maybe help me and show me an example for client that compress the xml based on EXI and send it to the server via HTTP.
Please advise.

Answer (score -1):

[exificient.js](https://github.com/EXIficient/exificient.js) is not a full EXI implementation yet.  Having said that, it currently needs schema information to work properly (and can NOT work schema-less). Therefore you need to pass to the EXIEncoder constructor grammars as indicated here https://github.com/EXIficient/exificient.js#howto-for-exi.

In the case of EXI4JSON there are built-in grammars in use.

Hope this helps,

-- Daniel